# Ubuntu is not connecting to wifi from iphone's personal hotspot

Tags: wireless, internet, iphone, hot-spot

When I try to connect my **ubuntu** with **iphone's personal hotspot** it won't connect in certain times, But sometimes it will recognize the device and connect to WiFi but it will **automatically disconnect** in 10 min or 15 min or so. I have no trouble with **Android Phones,**
I have checked with Samsung, Oppo and Vivo everything is working fine, but iPhone has some problems

**Logs of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
   Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
   Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
   Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't relate to settings or issues with the iphone itself (ie. settings that prevent connections at specific times, or drop connection at certain thresholds).  You confirm the Ubuntu works when not used with the iphone; so the likely cause from your description is with the iphone itself.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @guiverc I tried with other iPhones also like the iPhone 6s, X and 12 but it still won't connect, Maybe it will be a problem of iOS? but windows connects to iphone's hotspot without issues

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31 i added the logs of lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

Comment: [This answer may help](https://askubuntu.com/a/1370463/1460940)

Comment: Try `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` in terminal and reboot.  You may also want to see if the iPhone uses mixed encryption as TKIP causes problems with Qualcomm wifi

Answer (score 5):

Struggled with this issue yesterday and now I just got it working. Hasn't even been 15 minutes yet I don't think but writing this on a laptop running ubuntu that's connected to my iPhone's hotspot as I type.

Here is how I got mine to work.

went into my laptop (ubuntu) settings -> select network -> WiFi settings -> gear icon to the right of "{{myName}}'s iPhone" -> Security and then I changed it from "WPA3 Personal" to "WPA & WPA2 Personal" and it started working!

Comment: I had to change it the other way round :) (Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200)